# Masking credit card number if a CC number entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var cardNumber       = '4761640026883566';
var cardNumberDashed = '4761-6400-1234-2345';
var cardNumberSpaced = '4761 6400 1234 3523';

var ensureOnlyNumbers  = R.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
var maskAllButLastFour = R.replace(/[0-9](?=([0-9]{4}))/g, '*');
var hashedCardNumber   = R.compose(maskAllButLastFour, ensureOnlyNumbers);

document.body.innerHTML = hashedCardNumber(cardNumber)       + '<br/>' + 
                          hashedCardNumber(cardNumberDashed) + '<br/>' + 
                          hashedCardNumber(cardNumberSpaced);
```

My situation is a bit complicated, I have a `<textarea>` that I use as a message field in a chat window. **I want to mask all credit card numbers that was sent on this chat, but NOT every number**, because I do need a membership numbers from clients which is 10-15 digits numbers.

`<textarea id="postMessage"></textarea>`

I followed the code in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7odv6kfk/ but it works only on input fields that have credit card numbers.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Post your code in your question

Comment: You might want to find out if this is even legal. The PCI compliance folks would most likely want to slap you.

Comment: @BrianGottier How else to do it legally? I don't want my customers to send me credit card numbers, which they sometimes do!

Comment: Yes, if your customers are sending you credit card numbers, you're breaking the rules. Check stripe.com . I don't know if they do business in your country, but they're what I use.

Comment: @BrianGottier I don't want to see their credit card numbers, I want the script to change the credit card number to ***** so I don't see it!!

Comment: What's the point? If you can't see or do anything with the numbers, then why even have them? Maybe a better script would be to check the submission before being sent, and alert the user that credit card numbers are not allowed in the submission

Comment: @BrianGottier Great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find valid CC number formats and regular expressions matching them:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

The problem is that old VISA cards have 13 digits, American Express have 15 digits and some JCB cards have 15 digits. This conflicts with your membership numbers. Do you need to support 16-digit CC numbers then?

The following code shows how to replace 16-digit CC numbers with asterisks:

```
var re = /\b(\d[ -]?){15}\d\b/g;
var text = "My CC number is 4761640026883566 (or 4761-6400-1234-2345, or 4761 6400 1234 3523). My membership number is 1234567890123."

document.body.innerHTML = text.replace(re, "****");
```

Output:

`My CC number is **** (or ****, or ****). My membership number is 1234567890123.`

Comment: Thank you! Good thing I don't accept AMEX payments on my website :D

Comment: Added an example how 16-digit CC numbers can be replaced with "****".

Answer (score -1):

http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/ 
this library may help you it can detects only credit card number and avoid other numbers

var result = $('#cardnumber').validateCreditCard({ accept: ['visa', 'mastercard'] })

Comment: Thanks, but Qusai I want it to detect number during conversations, how can I run it this way?